# Merge sort - stack corruption error

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm writing a basic merge sort code in C++.  I'm getting stack corruption exception for variable b, when I run the below code in function merge().  I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong.  Any help is highly appreciated !!

Here's my code:

```
template <class T>
class mSort 
{
    void mergeSort(T *a, int low, int high);
    void merge(T *a, int low, int mid, int high);
public:
    mSort(T* a, int size);
};

template<class T>
mSort<T>::mSort(T *a, int size)
{
    mergeSort(a, 0, size);
}
template<class T>
void mSort<T>::mergeSort(T *a, int low, int high)
{
    int m;
    if (low < high)
    {
        m = (low + high) / 2;
        //printf("mergeSort:low[%d], mid [%d], high [%d]\n", low, m, high);
        mergeSort(a, low, m);
        mergeSort(a, m+1, high);
        merge(a, low, m, high);
    }
}

template<class T>
void mSort<T>::merge(T *a, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[20];
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            b[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        b[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = a[j++];

    k--;
    while (k >= 0) {
        a[low + k] = b[k];
        k--;
    }
}
```

Input array :
int a[20];

```
#define prep_intput_array(a,n)\
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)\
{\
    a[i] = rand() % 65535;\
}\
```

calling the merge sort routine like this :

```
mSort<int> m1(a, 20);
```

Code is based on the merge sort in this [link](http://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/merge-sort-program-in-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

high is passed with highest index in the array which is size-1 but you have passed size which is more than highest index in the array hence you might be getting an error.

Comment: Ah thanks so much, this was the issue.  Changed it to size-1 and now the stack corruption gone ...! Don't have enough rep to vote your answer up :(

Answer (score 1):

Your `high` is size of array, assume `20` means array index starting from `0` to `19`.

Looks like you are trying to access `b[20]` - > which is `21st` element of the array. Clearly out of bound.

Code below looks suspiciaous to me. It should check `j<high` (not `j<=high`)

```
while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
```

Same with code below:

```
 while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = a[j++];
```

Comment: if i change <= to < , stack exception goes away, but sorting is all wonky.  For ex here're the inputs/outputs:                        input array before sort
41->18467->6334->26500->19169->15724->11478->29358->26962->24464->5705->28145->23281->16827->9961->4
91->2995->11942->4827->5436->
After sort

41->11478->18467->6334->24464->26500->19169->15724->29358->26962->5705->28145->23281->16827->9961->4
91->2995->11942->4827->5436->

Comment: That might be some other issue. You can open new question for that because handling multiple issue may confuse other readers later.